# Should un responsive questions be removed?

Tags: support

While trying to answer the questions that have been labeled "unanswered" (and starting with the earliest ones) I noticed some have comments asking for details and further information. I further noticed that the OP had not replied to these queries although the post was 2-3 years old. Would it be practical to delete these posts? or is there the possibility it my be used by the OP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/976/strategies-for-dead-questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vote to close it, or flag it.

## Vote to close

- Click *close* (*if it's available to you*).
- Choose **off topic because...**
  [image]
- Choose **Not enough information**.
  [image]
- Then click the **Vote To Close** button.

This will add the question to the **Close Votes** review queue, where all eligible reviewers on the site can review the question.

## Flag

- Click *flag* (*If the option is available to you*).
- Choose either **should be closed...**, or **in need of moderator intervention**.
  [image]
- If you selected **should be closed...**, select **unclear what you're asking**.
  [image]
- Then click the **Vote To Close** button.
- If you selected **in need of moderator intervention**, describe the problem in the area provided.
  [image]
- Then click the **Flag Question** button.

This will either add the question to the **Close Votes** review queue, or to the moderators flag list.

Comment: thanks. got it.